# How to get AWS EC2 Instance object by id from java code?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I hava AmazonEC2Client connected to my account.
I can ask AWS my Reservations and Instances by

```
DescribeInstancesResult describeInstancesRequest = amazonEC2Client.describeInstances();
List<Reservation> reservations = describeInstancesRequest.getReservations();
Set<Instance> instances = new HashSet<Instance>();

for (Reservation reservation : reservations) {
   instances.addAll(reservation.getInstances());
}
```

But if I already know the Id of instance, can I somehow get Instance object for it without requesting reservations and all instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use :
[`describeInstances (DescribeInstancesRequest describeInstancesRequest)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#describeInstances(com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.DescribeInstancesRequest)) 
instead of 
[`describeInstances()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2Client.html#describeInstances()).

You can set the `instanceId` in the [`DescribeInstancesRequest`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DescribeInstancesRequest.html).
You need to use the [`setInstanceIds(Collection<String> instanceIds)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DescribeInstancesRequest.html#setInstanceIds(java.util.Collection)) method of [`DescribeInstancesRequest`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DescribeInstancesRequest.html) to set the instanceId(s) you are searching for.